# How to modify a Jelastic installation when wrapping a jps manifest in my own manifest?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, jelastic

The Jelastic Marketplace is full of interesting software. However, sometimes, they do not comply to my security needs. In those cases, I would like to write my own manifest that would install the manifest from the marketplace and add up the components that I need for my use-case. Let's take an example: I would like to wrap the [kubernetes installation](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/kubernetes) with the addition of a load-balancer. I would like to do something like this:

```yaml
type: install
name: My Example Manifest

onInstall:
  - install:
      jps: https://github.com/jelastic-jps/kubernetes/blob/1.23.6/manifest.jps
      envName: env-${fn.random}
      settings:
        deploy: cmd
        cmd: echo "do nothing"
        topo: 0-dev
        dashboard: general
        ingress-controller: Nginx
        storage: true
        api: true
        monitoring: true
        version: 1.23.6
        jaeger: false
  - addNodes:
      - nodeType: nginx-dockerized
        nodeGroup: bl
        count: 1
        fixedCloudlets: 1
        flexibleCloudlets: 4
```

The issue I am having here is that the manifest cannot add the nodes, because of the following error:

```
user [xyz] doesn't have any access rights to app [dashboard]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this manifest work? I tried to set `user: root` in the `addNodes` function but it doesn't help.

Of course, I am interested in suggestions involving one single install manifest. I know I could make it happen by first installing the kubernetes manifest and then running an update manifest that would add my load-balancer nodes. I would like, however, to package the whole thing within one single step, as described by my manifest above.